# not was returned from this render after auth().signOut()

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am getting the error that nothing was returned from this render after `auth().signOut()` while it should go to the login screen after signout. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```js
const signout = async () => {
  setShowLoading(true);
  try {
    const a = await auth().signOut().then(() => {
      console.log(a);
      setUser(null)
      setShowLoading(true)
      if (!user) {
        return navigation.navigate('Login')
      }
    });
  }
  catch (e) {
    setShowLoading(false);
    Alert.alert(
      e.message
    );
  }
};


return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Text>Welcome {user.email}</Text>
    <Button title="logout" onPress={() => signout()} />
    {showLoading &&
      <View style={styles.activity}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      </View>
    }
  </View>
);

};
```

Comment: Try to remove condition `if(!user)`

Comment: i have already tried it